How can I install Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu using a command like sudo apt install amass-common
I'm currently running Ubuntu, but I would like to install some of the security tools that are commonly available on Kali Linux. For instance, in Kali, I can install tools like amass-common simply by using:
sudo apt install amass-common

However, when I try to run this command on Ubuntu, I get an error saying that the package cannot be found.
Could someone guide me on how to properly install Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu? I'm looking for a method that allows me to use the apt package manager, similar to how it's done in Kali. Is there a specific repository I need to add or a different approach I should follow to access and install these tools on Ubuntu?


Add Kali Linux Repositories to Ubuntu:

echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list
2.Add Kali GPG Key:
wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -

3.Update APT package list: sudo apt update
4.Install Specific Kali Tools: sudo apt install amass
If you only want to install a few tools and avoid potential future conflicts, you can remove the Kali repositories after installing the tools:
Remove Kali Repositories After Installation (Optional):
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kali.list
Update APT:
sudo apt update 
I will also provide some additional options:
1)Using snap to Install Tools
Some tools can be installed via snap, which is a universal package manager:
Install using snap: `sudo snap install amass --classic`

2)Use Katoolin:
Katoolin is a script that simplifies the process of installing Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu:
Install Katoolin:
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
sudo pip3 install katoolin
Run Katoolin: sudo katoolin
Follow the on-screen instructions to install categories of tools.

Amass in-depth DNS enumeration and network mapping tool can be installed without enabling any potentially unsafe additional repositories by installing the amass snap package with the following command.
sudo snap install amass

To start Amass from the terminal type the command amass
Subcommands: 

    amass intel - Discover targets for enumerations
    amass enum  - Perform enumerations and network mapping
    amass viz   - Visualize enumeration results
    amass track - Track differences between enumerations
    amass db    - Manipulate the Amass graph database

The OWASP Amass Project has developed a tool to help information security  professionals perform network mapping of attack surfaces and external asset  discovery using open source information gathering and active reconnaissance  techniques.
For general information about installing other Kali Linux tools in Ubuntu refer to Proper Installation of Kali linux tools in Ubuntu. If you don't need to install too many Kali Linux tools, check first if the software that you are trying to install is included in the default Ubuntu software repositories and read the warning at LionSec / katoolin GitHub webpage.
